# E-Mail with Information from List

Tags: list, workflow, email, approval

I have a calendar that employees use to request time away. When a user adds an item to the calendar, an e-mail is generated to the manager asking for approval/declination of the time away. What I cannot figure out is how to bring in all the information already on the calendar for the day. For instance, if I request tomorrow off, but Tom Stack has time already, the e-mail should appear as such:

**Start Email**

Coolest Person has requested time off for 08/06/2016.

Other individuals who have time off on 08/06/2016:
Tom Stack - 4 hours from 8:00 AM to 12:00 PM

**End Email**

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Create an [ItemAdded event receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) for your calendar list.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
```

In the event receiver, read the properties of the entry created. You need the date of the event as well:

```
DateTime eventDate = DateTime.Parse(properties.ListItem["EventDate"]"].ToString(), null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Using this `eventDate` create and run a `CAML` query (using `DateRangesOverlap`, `Today` and `CalendarDate`, see example from [here](http://mossknowledge.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/caml-queries-daterangesoverlap-and.html#!/2012/05/caml-queries-daterangesoverlap-and.html)) to get all of the items for the same day:

```
<Where>
          <DateRangesOverlap>
               <FieldRef Name='EventDate'>
               <FieldRef Name='EndDate'>
               <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID'>
               <Value Type='DateTime'>
                    <Today/>
               </Value>
          </DateRangesOverlap>
     </Where>
```

and

```
query.CalendarDate = {target date};
```

Build the message text based on the info you have, and send the mail.